# Is there a way to preserve the types in a vararg parameter?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, variadic-functions

My question is it is possible to do something like:

```
fun <T, R> someFunction(vararg sources<out T>, doSomething: (vararg sources<out T>) -> R) {
    // do something here
}
```

So if I do something like:

```
someFunction(SomeType<A>(), SomeType<B>(), SomeType<C>()) { a: A, b: B c: C ->
    // do Something
}
```

Basically, the higher ordered function needs to require all the parameter types.

The reason why I'm asking this is that I would like to simplify code that are like this:

```
inline fun <T1, T2, R> MediatorLiveData<out R>.merge(source1: LiveData<out T1>, source2: LiveData<out T2>, crossinline merger: (T1?, T2?) -> R?) {
    addSource(source1) {
        this.value = merger.invoke(source1.value, source2.value)
    }
    addSource(source2) {
        this.value = merger.invoke(source1.value, source2.value)
    }
}

inline fun <T1, T2, T3, R> MediatorLiveData<out R>.merge(source1: LiveData<out T1>, source2: LiveData<out T2>, source3: LiveData<out T3>, crossinline merger: (T1?, T2?, T3?) -> R?) {
    addSource(source1) {
        this.value = merger.invoke(source1.value, source2.value, source3.value)
    }
    addSource(source2) {
        this.value = merger.invoke(source1.value, source2.value, source3.value)
    }
    addSource(source3) {
        this.value = merger.invoke(source1.value, source2.value, source3.value)
    }
}

inline fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, R> MediatorLiveData<out R>.merge(source1: LiveData<out T1>, source2: LiveData<out T2>, source3: LiveData<out T3>, source4: LiveData<out T4>, crossinline merger: (T1?, T2?, T3?, T4?) -> R?) {
    addSource(source1) {
        this.value = merger.invoke(source1.value, source2.value, source3.value, source4.value)
    }
    addSource(source2) {
        this.value = merger.invoke(source1.value, source2.value, source3.value, source4.value)
    }
    addSource(source3) {
        this.value = merger.invoke(source1.value, source2.value, source3.value, source4.value)
    }
    addSource(source4) {
        this.value = merger.invoke(source1.value, source2.value, source3.value, source4.value)
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the following function:

```
fun <T, R> someFunction(vararg sources: LiveData<out T>, doSomething: (sources: Array<out LiveData<out T>>) -> R) {
    // ...

    doSomething(sources)
}
```

It seems we can't use modifier `vararg` in lambda expression `doSomething`, replacing it with `Array` will work.

EDIT:
So basically you will be able to do something like the following for different number of sources without creating additional functions like in your example:

```
fun <T, R> someFunction(vararg sources: LiveData<out T>, doSomething: (sources: Array<out LiveData<out T>>) -> R) {
    sources.forEach {
        addSource(it) {
            doSomething.invoke(sources)
        }
    }
}

// Call someFunction with different number of args:
val l1: LiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()
val l2: LiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
val l3: LiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

// Call with two args:
someFunction(l1, l2) { sources: Array<out LiveData<out Any>> ->
    val data1 = sources[0] as LiveData<Int>
    val data2 = sources[1] as LiveData<String>
    // do your work here   
}
// Or Call with three args:
someFunction(l1, l2, l3) { sources: Array<out LiveData<out Any>> ->
    val data1 = sources[0] as LiveData<Int>
    val data2 = sources[1] as LiveData<String>
    val data3 = sources[2] as LiveData<String>
    // do your work here   
}
```

Comment: I don't get it can you explain this futher? How can this simplify my methods above?

Comment: will that work for different Types. Like `someFunction(liveDataOfString, liveDataOfInteger)` and it will enforce that the `someFunction(liveDataOfString, liveDataOfInteger) { someString, someInteger ->  // do something here }`?

Comment: Yes, it will work for different types. But the lambda will look like this: `someFunction(l1, l2, l3) { sources: Array<out LiveData<out Any>> -> ... }`

Comment: Please see my edits. If I understood correctly, you need just cast it to appropriate type, e.g.: ` val data1 = sources[0] as LiveData<Int>`

Comment: Thats what I though too. I just hoped there could be some other way. Anyway I'll mark your answer now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I didn't find better way, avoiding casting. But, as I figured out, we can't use modifier `vararg` in lambda expression. So I replaced it with an `Array`.

Comment: Yep! I actually discovered that too. I actually agree with your solution.